# javascript not working properly with php

Tags: php, javascript

I have tried to call simple javascript function in php. I can't call that function showResult().I don't know what is wrong with this code. Can you please check for me? I appreciate your help. 
http://www.mediafire.com/?hycdzegki1n79lg 
With regards,

Updated: Yes. I knew that it is reparative question (also that one is now closed with negative ) but I think problem is different. Actually, I can write other similar to this just that I am stuck for  this one. I can't post well here for whole or necessary function because after I post, it become messy. I am sorry for making trouble to you. What link shall I upload?

```
<?php
echo '<select name="companyNameList" onchange="showResult()" >';
for ($row = 0; $row < 2; $row++)
{
echo '<option value="'.$placement[$row]["company_name"].'">'.$placement[$row]    ["company_name"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of the Related Section

Comment: you are not calling the function, you just print a select. I think your javascript code isn't right.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The php code looks good. But the title makes no sense: php won't call a javascript function. One can invoke the js function when looking at the rendered html page and changing the selected option. Please provide more details

Comment: don't link mediafire please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues.

HTML structure and Form tags are not proper, they should be in body

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <form>
     </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

this is the structure you should follow

They way you are writing your onChange function is correct, but the issue in my opinion is in the showResult JS function

in the function you have used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult()
{
    var companyName = companyNameList.value;
    var insertvalue = d.getElementById('lblCompanyName');
    insertvalue.innerHTML = companyName
    //    document.getElementById("lblCompanyName").value=document.getElementById("companyNameList").value;
        <?php echo "hi";?>

}
</script>
```

please note that `<?PHP echo 'hi'; ?>` will only out put 'hi' in the JS which means nothing and may cause JS errors. you should use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showResult()
{
    var companyName = companyNameList.value;
    var insertvalue = d.getElementById('lblCompanyName');
    insertvalue.innerHTML = companyName
    //    document.getElementById("lblCompanyName").value=document.getElementById("companyNameList").value;
        <?php echo "alert('hi');";?>

}
</script>
```

I hope these will solve your issues

**EDIT**

Give an id to your dropdown select `companyNameList`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult()
    {

        <?php echo "alert('hi');";?>
        var companyName = document.getElementById("companyNameList");
        var companyNameValue = companyName.options[companyName.selectedIndex].value;
        var insertvalue = document.getElementById('lblCompanyName');

        insertvalue.innerHTML = companyNameValue;
    }
</script>
```

Please install `firebug` in your firefox to catch any errors in script

**EDIT COMPLETE CODE**

Check this code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','xerox_test');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$statement = "SELECT * from form_results";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$statement);
$placement= array(); 
$i=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{    
    $rowktl[$i] = $row;
    $placement[$i]['company_name'] = $rowktl[$i]['company_name'];
    $i++;
   }
?>
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult()
    {

        <?php echo "alert('hi');";?>
        var companyName = document.getElementById("companyNameList");
        var companyNameValue = companyName.options[companyName.selectedIndex].value;
        var insertvalue = document.getElementById('lblCompanyName');

        alert(companyNameValue);
        insertvalue.innerHTML = companyNameValue;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">  
<p>Select the data</p> 
<?php
echo '<select name="companyNameList" id="companyNameList" onchange="showResult()" >';
for ($row = 0; $row < 2; $row++)
{
    echo '<option value="'.$placement[$row]["company_name"].'">'.$placement[$row]["company_name"].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
<br>
<input name="Submit" type="button" class="Submit" value="Submit"  onClick="showResult()" />
<table border=2>
    <tr>
        <td>Case Number <br></td>
        <td>Technican ID <br></td>
        <td>Company Name <br><label id="lblCompanyName">Here</label> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Model Number <br></td>
        <td>Machine Serial Number<br></td>
        <td>Company Address<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Customer Name<br><?php echo json_encode($placement[0]['customer_name']);?></td>
        <td>Customer Email<br></td>
        <td>Contact Number<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan=3>Remark<br></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added the `id="companyNameList"` to `<select>` in php code above the loop. Also updated the JS function.

Now if you use this, can you see the selected value in alert? If you can not see that it means we are not yet getting the selected value. If you see the proper value, it means the assignment is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have wrote roughly and I didn't follow. I have changed according to what you said. But, still it did't update the label. I can see the required text in the drop down list (will update to label). So, I think showResult() is not working.

Comment: did it gave the alert message with HI in it?

Comment: Please check this question for JS fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript I also have updated my answer

Comment: No. it didn't alert . How shall I do?

Comment: remove all the code, or comment all except the alert line, and chck, may be error in JS is not allowing you to alert. Check updated answer

Comment: I have put id here. <td>Company Name <br><label id="lblCompanyName">Here</label> </td>......Now, I see the alert. So, showResult() is now working. But, it didn't update the label. How shall I continue?

Comment: check updated answer, and ready thoroughly

Comment: I really thanks for your help. now it work. Next time, I will do this way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The javascript isn't the problem, I made a simple js-fiddle for you, I think the problem is your php code, and what it generates. Could you post the full html that the php code renders please?

I think `$placement[$row]['company_name']` might not contain a string.

Here the jsfiddle showing you the js.
http://jsfiddle.net/HWFQH/1/

Otherwise try this, it might be a bit easier to read for you, if it's in the view / html code of yours.

```
<select name="companyNameList" onchange="showResult()">
<?php for ($row = 0; $row < 2; $row++):?>
     <option value="<?php echo $placement[$row]["company_name"];?>">
          <?php echo $placement[$row]["company_name"];?>
      </option>
<?php endfor;?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I can see the required text in the drop down list (will update to label). So, I think showResult() is not working. I want to post here but I think not enough space. May I know how I can pass to you?

Comment: @KhantThuLinn: Edit your initial question with all the necessary information and source code.